# CSS Units for Material Design

Tags: css, material-design

I'm hoping to follow Material Design (not explicitly installing MD) using CSS, but the units are a little confusing for me. I know that most elements are sized and positioned on a 4dp or 8dp grid, but I'm not sure how that will translate into CSS units. I know using rems/ems are generally good practice for scalablity, but they aren't mentioned in Material Designed (at least in terms of size/positioning).

For instance, a `<button>` tag might be said to have 8'dp' padding; I want the button to scale for different devices, and I want to reuse as much CSS as possible.

Should I replace "dp" with "px" and just use pixel units, and use varying breakpoints to support different devices? Or should I approach this differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use pixel units, we don't have a native CSS unit that converts the passed value to a 4 (or 8) multiple.

And to keep the styles on the same scale for different devices you can use the following tag on your HTML file, inside `<head>`:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

On W3Schools you can find [a better explanation for the `<meta>` viewport element](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp):

> A `<meta>` viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.
>
> The `width=device-width` part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).
>
> The `initial-scale=1.0` part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.